# Replacing div content of php using ajax callback within an ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The code below is found in index.php. On click, the $selection variable is passed through ajax to ajax.php, which processes data and replaces #div1 with html.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").on("click", function(){
       var $selection = 'data to be transmitted';
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data: { 'selection' : $selection },
           success: function(data) {
               $( "#div1" ).html(data);
           }
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

Then, ajax.php processes $selection using $_GET['selection']. However, at the end of ajax.php lies another ajax call to ajax2.php, passing $selection2:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".header").on("click", function(){
      var $selection2 = 'depends on $selection from ajax.php';
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'ajax2.php',
          data: { 'another_selection' : $selection2 },
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              $( "#div2" ).html(data);
          }
      });
  });
};
</script>
```

Both div1 and div2 are found in index.php. My issue is the second ajax call (to ajax2.php) does not work--it does not replace #div2 with the html received from ajax2.php.

Any ideas? I know that the data being returned is correct, as I logged it in console and it is the correct html. My guess is that the "$( "#div2" ).html(data);" line does not work, as it is found in the ajax.php file and not index.php where #div2 actually resides.

Comment: You’re aware that the second script does not actually _make_ an AJAX request, but registers a click handler on an element only? (Only when that click event happens, would the AJAX request be performed.)

Comment: Why don't you make the second AJAX call from the `success` function of your first one? Or even better, just return all of the data you need in one request

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing bind/routine conflicts, try to unify those ajax calls into one, inside callback or outside:

Inside callback:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").on("click", function(){
       var $selection = 'data to be transmitted';
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data: { 'selection' : $selection },
           success: function(data) {
               $( "#div1" ).html(data);
              var $selection2 = 'depends on $selection from ajax.php';
              $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: 'ajax2.php',
                 data: { 'another_selection' : $selection2 },
                 success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $( "#div2" ).html(data);
                 }
              });
           }
       });

   });
});
</script>
```

Ouside callback:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").on("click", function(){
       var $selection = 'data to be transmitted';
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data: { 'selection' : $selection },
           success: function(data) {
               $( "#div1" ).html(data);
           }
       });
            if ($selection == something)
               var $selection2 = 'depends on $selection from ajax.php';
              $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: 'ajax2.php',
                 data: { 'another_selection' : $selection2 },
                 success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $( "#div2" ).html(data);
                 }
              });

   });
});
</script>
```

But the best approach it's to unify ajax.php and ajax2.php routines into one, developing a cleaner script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").on("click", function(){
       var $selection = 'data to be transmitted';
       if ($selection == something)
          var $selection2 = 'selection2 data/condition that depends selection';
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data: { 
                 'selection': $selection,
                 'anotherselection': $selection2        
                 },
           success: function(data) {
               $( "#div1" ).html(data);
               $( "#div2" ).html(data); 
           }
       });

   });
});
</script>
```

Into your php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['selection'])){
    //first ajax routine
}

if (isset($_GET['anotherselection'])){
   //second ajax routine (ajax2.php)
}
```